# NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error. Python code

Tags: python, regex

```
import os
import re 
from collections import Counter
fileNames = []
textInfo = []

currentDirectoryPath = os.getcwd()
print(currentDirectoryPath)


regexp = re.compile(
    r'(?P<clientIP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+\['
    + '(?P<timestamp>\d{2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/\d\d\d\d).+\"'
    + '(?P<action>[A-Z]{3,4}).+\"'  
    + '(?P<statuscode>[1-5][0-9][0-9])'
    )

#(?P<clientIP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+\[(?P<timestamp>\d{2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/\d\d\d\d).+\"(?P<action>[A-Z]{3,4}).+\" (?P<statuscode>[1-5][0-9][0-9])


os.chdir("/content/drive/log")
currentDirectoryPath = os.getcwd()
listOfFileNames = os.listdir(currentDirectoryPath)
#for files in listOfFileNames :
    #print(files) 


f = open('access_1.log', 'r')
matched = 0
failed = 0
cnt_clientIPs = Counter()


for line in f:
    m = re.match(regexp, line)
    if m:
        cnt_clientIPs.update([m.group('clientIP')])
        matched += 1
    else:
        failed += 1

    print("""
    client.........: %s
    timestamp......: %s
    actions........: %s
    statuscode.....: %s
    """ %
      (m.group('clientIP'),
      m.group("timestamp"),
      m.group("action"),
      m.group("statuscode"),
    ))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-bc8f84e43987> in <module>()
     46     statuscode.....: %s
     47     """ %
---> 48       (m.group('clientIP'),
     49       m.group("timestamp"),
     50       m.group("action"),

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I keep getting no attribute error on the last print statement. My regex is able to run but when I'm not able to print it. I was able to print it if I take the status code out and out of the regular expression. I don't know why I keep getting a no attribute error when there is attributes for it. 
Here is a line of testcode to help you run it. I was suppose to take it from a file but I'm unable to upload the file here. 
'109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"

Comment: As well it supposes to test around 500 lines or the max amount of lines in the given file.

Comment: Suppose `m = re.match(regexp, line)` fails and you get None. There is an `if` but then it ends and you execute `m.group('clientIP')` anyway. BTW, please post the full traceback message so we don't have to guess.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bc8f84e43987> in <module>()
     46     statuscode.....: %s
     47     """ %
---> 48       (m.group('clientIP'),
     49       m.group("timestamp"),
     50       m.group("action"),

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Just move the print inside the if

Comment: @tdelaney ^ I hope that helps

Comment: @tdelaney when i do that nothing prints.

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback, formatted as code, in your question itself.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille just did that. Thank you for guiding me. This is my first time asking a question.

Comment: Sounds like the regex never matches. You want to put `r` on the front of all of those strings. How about `print(repr(line))` right before the regex and post a sample of the data.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried to put the r in front of all the lines in the regex and did the print(repr(line)) substituting the line with my code. Also, should I make a comment for the sample of data? or added to where I have my paragraph?

Comment: @Thebul500 - could very well be true. I haven't gone through the regex.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I just posted the regex with the r in front. Is this what are you telling me to avoid?

Comment: @Thebul500 - wait, is the string you want to compare '109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"` ? Is that exact?

Comment: You forgot the whitespace `\s*` just before the status code. Adding it works, see https://regex101.com/r/XB31hj/1

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, this code is for a log analyzer so the string is that. I want to get the IP, timestamp, action, and status code from the given line. I'm unable to print or layout all the test lines as I'm not a high enough level in here.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I will try that. Do I add that part in the regex? I'll also look at the link you sent me.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That kinda worked!  But It was able to print something this time. I just still got the same error.

Comment: @tdelaney I just updated it and this is what I got now.

Comment: @daniel  A R F Yes! that works!!

Comment: Nice! I added an answer while you were commenting. Also, please do not edit your question to include its solution, all the comments and answers would become irrelevant. I'll revert it to its previous version. If you want to indicate that an answer solves your problem, you can do so by accepting it, and you may upvote it if you have enough reputation.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille how do I accept it?

Comment: There is a check mark on the left of the answer

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for helping me! I appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex didn't allow for the space before the status code that is present in your sample data.

Also, note that you don't need to escape the double quotes `"` if you enclosed your string in single quotes. If you escape them with `\"` and use a raw string, you'll introduce a litteral backslash.

The regex I used, which you can see in action at https://regex101.com/r/XB31hj/1, is:

```
regexp = re.compile(
    r'(?P<clientIP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+\['
    + r'(?P<timestamp>\d{2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/\d\d\d\d).+"'
    + r'(?P<action>[A-Z]{3,4}).+"'  
    + r'\s*(?P<statuscode>[1-5][0-9][0-9])'
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```py
...

for line in f:
    m = re.match(regexp, line)
    if m:
        cnt_clientIPs.update([m.group('clientIP')])
        matched += 1
    else:
        failed += 1
        continue
...
```